# Aplicação REST no Ophenshift

Tags: java, api, rest, netbeans, openshift

Eu criei uma aplicação REST pelo netbeans, e agora quero subi-la para o OpenShift.

Eu estou usando o eclipselink para fazer a persistência dos dados, então eu uso uma classe `AbstractFacade<T>` para fazer o CRUD básico, como segue:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
private final Class<T> entityClass;

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}

public void remove(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
}

public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
}

public List<T> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
    [...]
}

public int count() {
    [...]
}

}
```

Então eu herdo essa classe para a classe que eu desejo executar o CRUD, por exemplo:

```
@Stateless
@Path("categoria")
public class CategoriaFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Categoria> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "api_api_war_1.0PU")
private EntityManager em;

public CategoriaFacadeREST() {
    super(Categoria.class);
}

@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(Categoria entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Categoria entity) {
    super.edit(entity);
}

@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    super.remove(super.find(id));
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Categoria find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return super.find(id);
}

@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Categoria> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}

[...]

}
```

como podem ver eu utilizo a anotação `@Path("categoria")`, uma vez que estou utilizando uma API REST e possuo uma herança da classe Application com a anotação `@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/api")`.

Mas quando tento acessar `meuhost.com/api/categoria`, por exemplo, recebo o seguinte erro:

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException

```
**exception**

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:421)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

**root cause**

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.rhcloud.api.encontreoferta.model.service.AbstractFacade.findAll(AbstractFacade.java:42)
    com.rhcloud.api.encontreoferta.model.service.CategoriaFacadeREST.findAll(CategoriaFacadeREST.java:68)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:164)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:181)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:101)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:305)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

---

O meu problema se resume a `EJB`.

Eu realmente queria separar a lógica em um servidor e a interface em outro... E mais algumas coisas. Por isso pensei em usar `EJB`.

Porem o servidor do OpenShift é o Tomcat, mas Tomcat é apenas um Servlet Container, ou seja, ele implementa as especificações de Servlets e `JSP`. Tomcat não implementa `EJB`.

Como está descrito em http://solucoestecnologia.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/diferencas-entre-ejb-tomcat-e-glassfish.html

E esse é o motivo da minha aplicação não rodar no OpenShift, eu preciso usar o glassfish para atender os requisitos do meu projeto...

No meu caso o `EntityManager` vem null, por que não foi possível fazer a injeção do `EJB` corretamente.

> Gostaria agradecer grandemente o [Bruno César](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23885/bruno-c%C3%A9sar) pela grande ajuda.

Comment: Só dá `404` no openshift, local está OK?

Comment: Cara sim, só que eu fiz uma aplicação web java comum, e o openshift parece que utiliza maven... E se eu crio uma aplicação web maven e tento criar REST acontece o mesmo erro. O Maven tem alguma dependência especifica para cirar REST?

Comment: Você está usando JAX-RS, então há sim dependências. Por isto a pergunta de que se funciona localmente, por que se sim, então não é problema no projeto em si, e sim no deploy no openshift. O "**Cara sim**" significa que está funcionando localmente é?

Comment: Rs... "**Então cara**" funciona local se não for Maven, mas eu estava dando uma olhada aqui e coloquei o `Jersey-3.1.1` e agora já não está mais dando erro `404` e sim `500 - Servlet execution threw an exception` ... Acredito que seja alguma outra dependência, por que não possuo servlet e acho que não preciso setar nada no `web.xml` ... certo?

Comment: Atualiza sua questão com sua configuração e o erro (*stacktrace*) que tento te ajudar.

Comment: Blz... Atualizei a pergunta com o erro. vlw

Comment: Para este erro, veja se esta resposta lhe ajuda: [AbstractMethodError using UriBuilder on JAX-RS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176811/30177448#30177448)

Comment: Não... O problema persiste. Mas agora eu reparei que estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem quando mando compilar `[WARNING] The POM for unknown.binary:javax.ws.rs-api-2.0:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available` isso teria alguma coisa a ver?

Comment: Cara eu removi algumas dependências inclusive a `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0:jar:SNAPSHOT` e deixei como você mostrou na outra resposta... Agora o erro é `Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException` quando eu tento usar o método `findAll` da minha classe de persistência... Vou atualizar a pergunta de novo... rsrs

Comment: Pelo erro provavelmente seu `EntityManager` está nulo, veja se está sendo injetado corretamente, se o `CDI` está funcionando, etc.

Comment: @BrunoCésar cara obrigado de verdade, mas o problema é que o OpenShift não atende a alguns requisitos do meu projeto... No Glassfish roda liso, mas se for tomcat, nem local roda... Mas vlw cara... Obrigado mesmo!!

Comment: Legal que tenha resolvido cara, mas lá roda EJB sim, lembro de criar aplicações JEE lá, usávamos `jboss-as`, não sei se aceitam outros containers full profile.